# Salesforce to Salesforce integration using Named Credentials

Tags: integration, connected-apps, salesforce2salesforce, auth-provider, namedcredentials

I am trying to build Salesforce to Salesforce integration using Named Credentials.

Followed the steps from below blog.

http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/salesforce-to-salesforce-integration-using-named-credentials-in-just-5-lines-of-code/

- Created Connected App in destination org
- Created Authorization Provider in source org
- Defined Named Credential in source org.

When I checked **Start Authentication flow on Save** and then save Named Credential and getting below error

> error=invalid_client_id&error_description=client%20identifier%20invalid

And also Authentication Status is Pending on Named Credential.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by updating Consumer Key.I didn't copied Consumer Key properly on Auth. provider in Destination org.After updating it and saving Named Credentials and new page opens up to authenticate Source Org and finally updated the Authentication Status to username of source org.